# добавить ProgressBar в tabPages

Tags: c#, winforms

есть элемент tabControl у него свойство tabPages и нужно добавить ProgressBar в первый элемент tabControl.
Но не могу понять как это сделать?

Comment: Не понял. Где должен оказаться прогрессбар? На первой вкладке контрола TabControl?

Comment: да в первой вкладе.

Comment: И в чем проблема? Что мешает это сделать?

Comment: я обращаюсь к tabControl.tabPages[0] а как добавить что то внутрь не пойму, нет ни свойства, ни методов для добавления и на гуглить не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно свойство **Control.Controls**:

```
tabControl.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(progressBar);
```

Comment: спасибо, а свойство Location будет относительно формы или tab контейнера?

Comment: Относительно родительского контрола, которым в конкретном случае будет TabPage (tabControl.TabPages[0]).